# Reading in Specific data from text file (C)

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to read in specific data from a variable file in fmt format. The data needed is the value of `a`,`b` and `c` as well as the `fft coefficients (width,height,depth)` (25,300,300) in this case.

An example would be from this file to assign the variables:
`a = 2.467`
`b = 30.000`
`c = 30.000`
 `width = 25`
 `height = 300`
 `depth = 300`.
The values of these will change however as the input file changes.

Currently the only way I can think of to read these in, is from their position in the text file. I do not like this however as it is prone to bugs if the text file changes slightly in layout. Can anyone suggest an alternate method (Is there something similar to the python re module in C)?

Please see an example text file below:

```
BEGIN header

       Real Lattice(A)               Lattice parameters(A)    Cell Angles
   2.4675850   0.0000000   0.0000000     a =    2.467585  alpha =   90.000000
   0.0000000  30.0000000   0.0000000     b =   30.000000  beta  =   90.000000
   0.0000000   0.0000000  30.0000000     c =   30.000000  gamma =   90.000000

 1                            ! nspins
25   300   300                ! fine FFT grid along <a,b,c>
END header: data is "<a b c> pot" in units of Hartrees
```

Comment: "prone to bugs if the text file changes slightly in layout" - if you can't rely on some file format to be constant/consistent it is hard for anyone to write a parser, even Python package developers. Everything you can do in Python can also be done in C.

Comment: If you're reading the file line by line `a`, `b` and `c` are simple to store because it's written like `a = value` in the file. But the `fft coefficients` are not that simple, however if the position of them is always the same (meaning e.g. that there is always written `fine FFT [...]` in that line) this is also easy.

Comment: Please give at least a link to the relevant specification of `fmt` format. I never heard of it.

Comment: BTW, where is that data coming from? Is it the output of some software whose source code you can study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first should **specify** and formalize **the *actual* [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format)** of your input (a single example is not enough). You might use, at least for documentation purposes, some [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation (I could guess but am not sure that `BEGIN` and `Lattice` are important in it, but the [fmt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fmt_(Unix)) wikipage don't mention them).

> An example would be from this file

That is a wrong approach. You need to know the *general* file format your program will be able to handle and that is part of your software design. So better specify it first.

Then you'll use usual [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques. Read also about [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis). Perhaps a [parser generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_generator) like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) could be helpful, or perhaps a simple [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) could be enough. Maybe your input format cares about lines, then you could read them one by one (e.g. with POSIX [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)) and parse each of them.

Reading the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition) is worthwhile.

> Is there something similar to the python re module in C

POSIX has `<regex.h>`; see [regcomp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html) ; Look also into [pcre2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pcre2.3.html). I am not sure it is relevant here.

Comment: In my opinion a bison parser and the studying of lexical analysis is too overkill for this simple question, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know what is the file format, so I cannot answer.

Comment: It is a fmt file

Comment: @WillC: but where is the formal specification of `fmt`? I never heard of it.

Comment: But that does not match at all your example. You need to find a more relevant file format specification.